# Getting a random number each time in a script

Tags: python, python-3.x, method-call

I'm having trouble with the following bit of code:

```
from random import randint
class character():
    __init__(self):
        #init stuff here
    def luck(self, Luck = randint(0, 3)):
        return Luck
```

I have to call this method multiple times in my script, for multiple instances, to get a different number each time. The problem that I'm having is that whenever i call this method, no matter from what instance, I always to get the same result. For example, in the following code:

```
Foo = character()
Bar = character()
for foobar in range(3):
    print(Foo.luck(), Bar.luck())
```

I'd get as my output:

```
1 1
1 1
1 1
```

By the way, in my code, I used `randint(0, 3)` as an argument for the `luck()` method because, in some specific situations, I'd like to assign values to it myself.

Back to the point, how can I get a different number each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a definition for the luck function. If the user specifies a number it will be returned. If instead no argument is given, Luck will be set from `randint` and that random value returned.

```
def luck(self, Luck = None):
    if Luck is None:
        Luck = randint(0,3)
    return Luck
```

Comment: not 0 would return True, hence it is better to do comparison to None directly.

Comment: That's a good point! Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In python, the default expressions that set the default values for function arguments are only executed once. This means that once you define the `luck` method, whatever value `randint()` spit out the first time will stay for all invocations.

To get a new random number every time the method is called, you need to call it inside the body of the method:

```
class Character(object):
    @staticmethod # required if you're not accepting `self`
    def luck():
        return randint(0, 3)
```

This will work as expected.

Comment: I don't think this solves the case when he would like to assign the value himself (although it does seem redundant to pass a value only to immediately return it).

Comment: I think that OP also wanted default argument for the "luck" function.

Comment: I thought so too, but that would defeat the purpose of having a random number returned so assumed it was just done that way by accident (clearly OP is still learning).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `None` or something for a default argument, check if you got `None` and if you did - call `randint()` (if not just return what you did get).
If you use `randint()` in the function deceleration it will randomize it only once.